# Is it possible to pull out a list of particular field values from a collection of generic objects in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have the following method in a class I am using for pagination in my app:

```
public static PagedList<T> ToPagedList(IEnumerable<T> source, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
        {
            var count = source.Count();
            var items = source
              .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
              .Take(pageSize).ToList();

            return new PagedList<T>(items, count, pageNumber, pageSize);
        }
```

In this method I am passing in a collection of generic objects as `IEnumerable<T> source` which regardless of type will always have an Id field. What I'd like to do is pull out all of the Ids for these objects and store them in a list to be passed into my PagedList constructor. Is this possible?

Comment: It's best to restrict `T` to some interface that defines `ID` property (not field, as fields cannot be defined in an interface). Short of that, you can use reflection, but it's expensive, and not type-safe!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the best way would be create an interface

```
public interface IBaseClass{
  public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

in this case you could change method header

```
static PagedList<T> ToPagedList<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, int pageNumber, int pageSize) 
                    where T : IBaseClass
```

and ids

```
var ids=items.Select(i => i.Id ).ToList();
```

Comment: why even make it generic.

Comment: Thank you, I decided to go this route.

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. You can use [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue?view=net-6.0) to get the value of a property.

```
item.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(item, null);
```

Edit: Respond to @CoolBots' comment

In case `Id` is a field, you can use [`GetField`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getfield?view=net-6.0) instead of `GetProperty`

```cs
item.GetType().GetField("Id").GetValue(item, null);
```

but if the item doesn't have the "Id" property, this code will fail, so remember to check for null.

Comment: I think in OP's case `Id` is a field, btw

Comment: Would you prefer reflection over eg an interface? If not/so why not/so?

Comment: @CaiusJard it depends. If you cannot change the architecture of the existing code, then reflection is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

An interface would be the best way, but you specifically said "field" and interfaces cannot contain fields.

You could get around this limitation with an abstract base class, but you cannot have multiple base classes on a single class (if applicable).

...All of this assumes that you have the ability to modify those classes.

Another way to do this would be:

```
public static PagedList<T> ToPagedList<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
{
    var count = source.Count();

    var items = source
        .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
        .Take(pageSize).ToList();

    var ids = items
        .Select(i => ((dynamic)i).Id)   // field is **always** named "Id"
        .Cast<int>()                    // its type is **always** int
        .ToList();
            
    return new PagedList<T>(items, count, pageNumber, pageSize/*, ids*/); // pass ids
}
```

This assumes the field in question is named "Id", and it is an `int`.

Adjust accordingly and handle potential errors.

I think I originally misunderstood the question, the comment by @Dusan caused me to reevaluate and update the code.

Comment: Why not just cast to `dynamic` in the `Select(o => o.Id)`? In that case you would have strong typing all the way.

Comment: @Dusan I think I understand now... I've reread the question, this makes much more sense.